# Mobile viewport not working?

Tags: mobile, viewport

Here is my entire HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=232, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        body {margin:0;width:200px;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background:#ccff99;color:#004000;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:6pt}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If I understand right, the body should be the full width of the viewport (`200+(1+15)*2 = 232`) so why is it that the page renders with a viewport width of 360? I would expect that of `device-width`, not an absolute `232`...

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) looks like a good article on your topic. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please sum up or quote the crucial bits here. Link rot happens. Link-only answers are subject to deletion. Thanks.

Comment: I'll have that in mind, thanks.